# verifying encryption in SSL post request in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, encryption, python-requests

On a locally running py3.6.4 on Pi3+ I need to make requests to interact with a mySQL database and need to send not just insensitive data but also user auth/credentials. More than one Pi's need to interact with the same data and each of the Pi's need to be able to run offline (for the case of internet connection refused) and database updates may be delayed, queued and need to be approved by user credentials. Thats why I did setup the SSL-connection.

My question to you is: How can I verify or check, if/that the sent data in fact are SSL encrypted? Or may I simply believe in tech and do not worry about?

I am using the following script (fragmented) which works and is doing data post how I expect it. The content of both dicts are sent correctly.

```
def posttest_s(payload):
    # payload is a dict {'one':'1 is one','two':'two is 2 forever'}
    import requests
    auth = get_auth_params() # external function, auth is a dict
    dataset = merge_dict(payload, auth) # external function
    remote_path = 'https://ssl.server.url/'
    url = remote_path+'posttest.php'
    r = requests.post(url, data=dataset, verify=True)
    return r.content
```

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: It all comes down to trusting the client library you are using - in this case `requests` offers verification by default: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification Of course if you're paranoid, you can read the source code for the library!

Comment: Since you don't trust the library and Python to do the right thing you have to look elsewhere: do a packet capture and check that the traffic matches your expectations (i.e. use of HTTPS in the code you've provided). Also, according to your code your problem has nothing to do with the database or PHP - the code is Python only and shows no connections to a database.  Please remove the unnecessary  tags or explain how they are important in the context of your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, you're right, removed the tags. The mentioned mySQL-connection was just to clarify the environmental conditions and the reason for SSL